# How to interpret/tune a multinomial classification with caret-GBM?

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, gbm, multinomial

Two questions

1. Visualizing the error of a model
2. Calculating the log loss

(1) I'm trying to tune a multinomial GBM classifier, but I'm not sure how to adapt to the outputs. I understand that LogLoss is meant to be minimized, but in the below plot, for any range of iterations or trees, it only appears to increase.

```
inTraining <- createDataPartition(final_data$label, p = 0.80, list = FALSE)
training <- final_data[inTraining,]
testing <- final_data[-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, verboseIter = FALSE, savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction= mnLogLoss)


gbmGrid1 <- expand.grid(.interaction.depth = (1:5)*2, .n.trees = (1:10)*25, .shrinkage = 0.1, .n.minobsinnode = 10)

gbmFit1 <- train(label~., data = training, method = "gbm", trControl=fitControl,
                   verbose = 1, metric = "ROC", tuneGrid = gbmGrid1)

plot(gbmFit1)
```

[image]

--
(2) on a related note, when I try to directly investigate mnLogLoss I get this error, which keeps me from trying to quantify the error.

```
mnLogLoss(testing, levels(testing$label)) : 'lev' cannot be NULL
```

Comment: I put together an answer for the graph. in general try to avoid asking multiple questions. I cannot reproduce your error without an example. Hence I encourage you to post another question if you still have problems with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you set the learning rate too high. So using an example dataset:

```
final_data = iris
final_data$label=final_data$Species
final_data$Species=NULL
inTraining <- createDataPartition(final_data$label, p = 0.80, list = FALSE)
training <- final_data[inTraining,]
testing <- final_data[-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, 
verboseIter = FALSE, savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction= mnLogLoss)

gbmGrid1 <- expand.grid(.interaction.depth = 1:3, .n.trees = (1:10)*10, .shrinkage = 0.1, .n.minobsinnode = 10)

gbmFit1 <- train(label~., data = training, method = "gbm", trControl=fitControl,
                   verbose = 1, tuneGrid = gbmGrid1,metric="logLoss")

plot(gbmFit1)
```

[image]

A bit different from yours but you can see the upward trend after 20. It really depends on your data but if you have a high learning rate, you arrive very quickly at a minimum and anything after that introduces noise. You can see this illustration from [Boehmke's book](https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/gbm.html) and also check out a more [statistics based discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354484/why-does-xgboost-have-a-learning-rate).

[image]

Let's lower the learning rate and you can see:

```
gbmGrid1 <- expand.grid(.interaction.depth = 1:3, .n.trees = (1:10)*10, .shrinkage = 0.01, .n.minobsinnode = 10)

gbmFit1 <- train(label~., data = training, method = "gbm", trControl=fitControl,
                   verbose = 1, tuneGrid = gbmGrid1,metric="logLoss")

plot(gbmFit1)
```

[image]

Note that you most likely need more iterations to reach a lower loss, like what you see with the first.